# how to add links of other pages in a html page in django

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, django-views

i was building a website in django. Since i m a beginner i don't know how to add links to other pages in html page present in a django project. I know that simply referencing other pages using href wont gonna work here. So please help by giving an example.

Comment: Look into `{% url %}` tag, and see how to use reverse url name of your page there. Django doc is quite clear on that.

Comment: Why wouldn't hrefs work? That's fundamental to the web, of course it will work.